# Prove that, $ \mathcal{E}(R)=\operatorname{tr}\left(R^{\top} L R\right) . $

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

In graph drawing, suppose we have G=(V,E), A graph drawing $ρ:V\rightarrow R^n$

We can formalize this by defining the energy of a drawing $R$ by
$$
\mathcal{E}(R)=\sum_{\left\{v_{i}, v_{j}\right\} \in E}\left\|\rho\left(v_{i}\right)-\rho\left(v_{j}\right)\right\|^{2},
$$

Proposition 2.1. Let $G=(V, W)$ be a weighted graph, with $|V|=m$ and $W$ an $m \times m$ symmetric matrix, and let $R$ be the matrix of a graph drawing $\rho$ of $G$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ (am $m \times n$ matrix). If $L=D-W$ is the unnormalized Laplacian matrix associated with $W$, then
$$
\mathcal{E}(R)=\operatorname{tr}\left(R^{\top} L R\right) .
$$

I don't know how do I prove this Proposition .....

Comment: Poroposition 2.1 of which document ? A reference [here](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis5150/cis515-14-graph-drawing.pdf)

Comment: Have a look at Lemma 4.2.2 in https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/~jwcalder/5467Notes.pdf This is the case that $n=1$, but the proof is similar for $n\geq 2$.